# Infowindow with buttons

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Hi iam trying to put buttons in the infowindow and when i click the button some action should takeplace atleast an alert.below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.98,77.59),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        (function() {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.98,77.59)
            });
            var content =   "<div id='tabs'>"+
                            "<form id='button'>"+
                            "<div>"+
                            "<input type='button' onclick='alert(infoWindow)'>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</form>"+
                            "</div>";  
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                infoWindow.setContent(content);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })();

    };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

here i can add the button but not able to make it work..Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you pass the value in the alert() as variable not as string. You need to pass this within single or double quote

```
var content =   "<div id='tabs'>"+
                "<form id='button'>"+
                "<div>"+
                "<input type='button' onclick='alert(\"infoWindow\")'>"+ // here
                "</div>"+
                "</form>"+
                "</div>";
```

now try with this.

Comment: @pratik-its working thankyou ..i missed that basic concept.what if i want that button to make more actions like triggering another event.

Comment: didn't able to understand "like triggering another event". You can call the function when the button click and then take action like onclick="myFunction()", with parameter onclick="myFunction('hello')"

Comment: like closing a marker function..can i do this    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('button1'), 'click', closeMarker());
});

function removeMarker(){

    alert('markerclosed');
}

Comment: but for this you already got the close button on top right of info window

Comment: As close the specific infowindow you need to keep that infowindow object and for closing the current infowindow close using infoWindow.close()

Comment: hi..as you mentioned in the second comment..when i click the button the my function should trigger..check below code google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                infoWindow.setContent(content);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('tabs'), 'click', message());
                function message(){
        alert('hiiiiii');}

Comment: i should get the alert statement from the function i pass to buttons onclick method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more out of InfoWindows and put HTML content in them I would recommend trying [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox). Check out the reference [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/infobox/docs/reference.html)

It has some of the additional things like closing the window build in.

Comment: these links are broken.

Comment: the utility library moved to github - I hoped the links, thanks for flagging!